# VB 2013 Error when trying to load designer or code for form "Make sure the application for file type (.vb) is installed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have worked on an application for some time now and after booting up my PC today, entering VS 2013, opening my project and trying to load my main form an error popped up.

> There is no editor available for (Location of form) Make sure the application for the file type (.vb) is installed

I have not uninstalled anything since last time the form worked, which was yesterday. My PC has a thing of sometimes randomly turning off, I don't know if that could have anything to do with the problem. I see several people with the same problem but they all seem to have a fix.

Involving re-installing some content that you have uninstalled and I do not think that is the case for me. When I execute the program VS prompts me saying that there are build errors, if I choose to run the last successful build the program works completely fine, but I still can't access the designer or code window.

Comment: Please I really need help on this problem! It just happened to another solution. I repaired VS but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to some reference file missing . Please make sure that all the references for the application is correctly added. If there is some file paths are shown like 'System can not find the reference specified' ,then remove the same and add them again from the correct path.